# Why do I have to const-qualify my function?

Tags: c++, constants

The following piece of code runs fine but if I omit the `const` qualifier after the parenthesis overload function, I get a compile error saying:

> "passing 'const matrix' as 'this' argument of 'double& matrix::operator()(unsigned int, unsigned int)' discards qualifiers".

Why does the assignment `dest(i,j)=src(i,j)` trigger the compiler error? This assignment line isn't trying to change the constant object `src` (it is changing `dest` which is not constant) so why does the paranthesis overload function have to be const-qualified?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct matrix
{
protected:
  double* mat; //array that stores matrix components
public:
  unsigned nrows; unsigned ncols; //ncols = number of columns, nrows = number of rows
  matrix(unsigned m, unsigned n): nrows(m), ncols(n)
  {
    mat = new double[m*n]; //creates an array of size nrows*ncols
    for (unsigned k=0; k<m*n; k++)
      mat[k]=0.0;
  }
  double& operator()(unsigned i, unsigned j) const //parenthesis operator (to access matrix components)
  {
    if (i>nrows || i<1 || j>ncols || j<1) throw(-1); //index out of bounds
    return mat[(i-1)*ncols+(j-1)];
  }
 ~matrix() {delete[] mat;}
};

void copy(const matrix& src, matrix& dest)
{
  unsigned m=src.nrows; //sets m to number of rows
  unsigned n=src.ncols; //sets n to number of columns
  for (unsigned i=1; i<=m; i++)
    for (unsigned j=1; j<=n; j++)
      dest(i,j)=src(i,j); //copies all the components of src to dest
}

int main()
{
  matrix A(2,1);
  A(1,1)=11;
  A(2,1)=21;
  matrix B(2,1);
  copy(A,B);
  std::cout << B(1,1) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem is exactly what the error message says.  You're trying to pass a `const` object pointer to a method that isn't `const`.

Comment: learn [const correctness](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/const-correctness.html)

Comment: side note: array indices start with 0, not with 1

Comment: *"if I omit ... both this and the one after the parenthesis overload, I get an exception"* - what exception? this should be working, I think.

Comment: *it is changing dest which is not constant* - `dest` is not const, but the return value of `dest()` is